Finding the value of a large summation.

$$\ell = \lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+2^nk}$$
Find $\boldsymbol{2\ell}$

I thought about this problem for a long time and I am totally not able to proceed. Can someone give atleast a hint?

Please use MathJax instead of images in your post.

A bit confusing to me with $r$ being used twice as a summation index.

Partial answer:
As the second sum does not depends on the summation index of the first one you can rewrite it as
$$
\lim_{ k \to \infty} \left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{1+k 2^m}\right) \left(\sum_{r=1}^k \dfrac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r}\right)
$$
The second factor is the Mercator series (i.e. the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$) around $x=1$. As such you have
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^k \dfrac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r}=\log(2)
$$
The value of the partial sum of the first series can be found here here.
The series converges for any $k>0$, I can't think to any way to actually find the asymptotic

$$0<\sum_{r=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}r<1$$ and
$$0<\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{1+2^nk}<\frac1k\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^n}=\frac2k$$$$\implies\ell=0.$$

Thanks @Marco for having notified me of your recent restoration of the question. I updated my answer accordingly.  Shouldn't we both delete these comments?

Too long for a comment.
When you will be familiar with special function (namely the q-polygamma and the Lerch transcendent), you will be able to find a closed form for
$$S_k=\sum_{r=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+2^nk}$$
To make the story short, asymptotically
$$S_k\sim\frac{3 \log (2)}{2 k}$$
Try is with Excel.
